# Multiple odbc connections to speed up data read

Tags: ms-access, odbc

Is it possible to configure MS ACCESS to open multiple odbc connections to a single source and speed up data reading?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to speed up data reading, use Pass-Through SQL.  As long as you're not trying to update anything you can use the power of the server to speed up the data collection.  Beyond that, Jonny Bones is right- more connections will just split the time between available resources.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Access is a "Client-Side" application.  This means it pulls the entire dataset to the client, performs operations and then pushes it back out.  Opening multiple connections would just cause it to pull multiple datasets simultaneously, thus slowing it down.  It can only pull data as fast as the pipe allows.